# Execute one feature at a time during application execution

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate in this way; during application execution, I get the test files from another source and I create feature files based on what I get.

then I iterate over the list of the tests and execute them.

My problem is that by using

```
CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, resultDirectory);
```

I execute all the tests at every iteration, which causes tests to be executed multiple times.

Is there a way to execute one test at a time during application execution (I'am fully aware of the empty test class with annotation to specify one class but that doesn't seem to serve me here)

I thought about creating every feature file in a new folder so that I can specify the path of the folder that contains only one feature at a time, but CucumberRunner.parallel() accepts Class and not path.

Do you have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set a single file (or even directory path) to run via the [annotation](https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-options):

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:animals/cats/cats-post.feature")
```

I think you already are aware of the [Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) which can take one file at a time, but you won't get reports.

Well you can try this, set a System property `cucumber.options` with the value `classpath:animals/cats/cats-post.feature` and see if that works. If you add tags (search doc) each iteration can use a different tag and that would give you the behavior you need.

Just got an interesting idea, why don't you generate a single feature, and in that feature you make `call`s to all the generated feature files.

Also how about you programmatically delete (or move) the files after you are done with each iteration.

If all the above fails, I would try to replicate some of this code: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/Karate.java